# What happens to a Django form's attributes after the .clean method?

Tags: django, forms

I have a form that, on the clean method, sets a form attribute:

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.CharField(…)
    …

    def __init___(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        …

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        self.user = User.objects.get(email=data.get("email"))
        …
        return data
```

I'm then trying to use `form.user` in the template if the form is submitted and there's an error.

For some reason, however, `form.user` is None, even though I can verify that self.user is being set.

I've made sure by making a fake validation error:

```
    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        self.user = User.objects.get(email=data.get("email"))
        raise forms.ValidationError("User found: %s" % self.user)
```

And then in the template:

```
The user is {{ form.user }}.

The form errors are {{ form.errors }}
```

Which results in:

```
The user is None.

The form errors are 
__all__
User found: Jordan Reiter.
```

Here's the interesting part: if I reverse the order displayed on the template, suddenly the value is set for form.user:

```
The form errors are {{ form.errors }}

The user is {{ form.user }}.
```

Which results in:

```
The form errors are 
__all__
User found: Jordan Reiter.

The user is Jordan Reiter.
```

What is going on here? Am I going to have to put something like

```
{% if form.errors %}<!-- do nothing -->{% endif %}
```

At the top just so `form.user` will be available in the template?

This is Django 1.4.15.

### Clarification

Just to clarify, I **am** calling `.is_valid` on the form. Without that call, `{{ form.errors }}` would be empty, but it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you aren't calling is_valid() in your view, form validation is triggered when you access .errors the first time (which in turn assigns SignupForm.user) :)

http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/forms/api.html#django.forms.Form.errors

Comment: I was calling `is_valid` **but** it was in a line like `if first_form.is_valid() and second_form.is_valid()` and of course the form in question was `second_form`. In cases where `first_form` was not valid `second_form.is_valid()` was never being called due to short-circuit evaluation. I plan on changing the code to evaluation the is_valid-ness of each form *before* putting them in the if statement.